# Ember Transactions: Moving objects between transactions

Tags: transactions, ember.js, ember-data

I have implemented a Route that has a transaction. When the user moved out of this route by clicking on a "back" button, I want the user to be able to confirm exiting and loosing any changes made by rolling back the transaction.

The problem is that if the user goes back into the route, Ember Data raises and error stating that:

```
Error: assertion failed: Models cannot belong to more than one transaction at a time.
```

This is even though I am explicitly calling remove() on the old transaction and add() to the new transaction (see the newTransaction() function below):

```
settingsDetails: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/details',
    transaction: MyApp.store.transaction(),

    doBackButton: function() {
        var dirty = MyApp.router.get('settingsDetailsController.content.isDirty');
        var doTransition = true;
        if (dirty) {
            var confirmDialog = confirm('You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to continue ? \n\nAny chances made will be lost!');
            doTransition = confirmDialog;
        }

        if (doTransition) {
            this.doResetSettingsDetails();
            MyApp.router.transitionTo('settings.settingsOverview');
        }
    },

    newTransaction: function() {
        var oldTransaction = this.get('transaction');
        var newTransaction = MyApp.store.transaction();

        var record = MyApp.router.get('settingsDetailsController').get('content');
        if (record) {
            oldTransaction.remove(record);
            newTransaction.add(record);
        }
        this.set('transaction', newTransaction);
    },

    doUpdateSettingsDetails: function() {
        this.get('transaction').commit();
        this.newTransaction();
    },

    doResetSettingsDetails: function() {
        this.get('transaction').rollback();
        this.newTransaction();
    },

    connectOutlets: function(router) {
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('settingsDetails');
        var record = MyApp.store.find(MyApp.PersonDetails, 1);
        this.get('transaction').add(record);
        router.get('settingsDetailsController').set('content', record);
    }
}),
```

Comment: If you still encounter this problem, could you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: ember-data does not have transactions anymore (and even in the latest version with transactions it was possible to move model from one transaction to an other one)

Comment: Joachim, can you answer this yourself?

Comment: Julian: The latest ember data, doesn't have transactions, so this question is not really valid any more...

Comment: Yes, but I want the question out of the "unanswered" list, coz I keep going to answer it :) so can you please either remove it, or answer it yourself? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember Data does not have transactions anymore, since the beta versions of Ember Data. This question is therefore not relevant any more.